# How to enable printer in terminal

Tags: printing

I know how to list printer and their state, but how do I enable a printer by its name in the Terminal.

I am using ubuntu 15.10
Thanks.

Comment: 15.10 is outdated and no longer supported. You should upgrade to one of the current Ubuntu releases like 16.04 LTS (long term support) or 17.10.

Answer (score 1):

```
lpadmin -E -d printername

man lpadmin
```

for more information.

Comment: Thanks, I did that, but printer stays disabled

Comment: cupsenable -E printerName seemed to work